# How can I view the contents of sql binary data fields?

Tags: sql, binary-data, sql-server-2005-express

Does anybody know how to view the contents of fields containing binary data in an MS SQL Server 2005 database?

Comment: If the data is binary... how would you "view" it?

Comment: It may be a string in which case viewing it in ascii or hex form would suffice.  At the moment all I see is <Binary data>.

Comment: use a query not the open table wizard, see my answer below

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depends if it is just text stored as binary or not, if it is then take a look at this

```
create table #bla (col1 varbinary(400))

insert #bla values(convert(varbinary(400),'abcdefg'))

select col1,convert(varchar(max),col1)
from #bla
```

output
0x61626364656667    abcdefg

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a utility to take some of the legwork out of it but this is a workable solution.